# If-Modified-Since overrides If-None-Match in the browser

Tags: http, http-headers, browser-cache, http-caching

I have a web server which provides an ETag for a particular url. When the browser performs a request for this url, it provides the http-header "If-None-Match" with the ETag-value contained in the previous response from the server for that url. Now, if I programatically add the request-header "If-Modified-Since" and set it to a either a future or past date (doesn't matter), the browser stops sending the "If-None-Match"-header. I have seen this in both FireFox and Chrome (not tested with any other browser). I can't conclude from the HTTP/1.1 spec that this should be the case. Why does this happen?

Here is a simple code example that will reproduce the scenario. The code assumes that the server responds with an Etag-header.

```
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open("GET", someUrl, true);
request.onreadystatechange = function(){};

// This statement makes the browser stop sending the "If-None-Match" header
request.setRequestHeader("If-Modified-Since", "Sat, 29 Oct 1994 19:43:31 GMT"); 

request.send(null);
```

Comment: You may want to read http://greenbytes.de/tech/webdav/draft-ietf-httpbis-p4-conditional-21.html instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Now, if I programatically add the request-header "If-Modified-Since" and set it to a either a future or past date (doesn't matter), the browser stops sending the "If-None-Match"-header.

They shouldn't, if the server provides in both an Etag and Last-Modified header for the given resource:

> HTTP/1.1 clients [...] if both an entity tag and a Last-Modified value have been
>           provided by the origin server, SHOULD use both validators in
>           cache-conditional requests. This allows both HTTP/1.0 and
>           HTTP/1.1 caches to respond appropriately.

Edit: when calling `XmlHttpRequest.open()`, the implementation prepares a request using an `nsIHttpChannel`, using among others the `If-Modified-Since` and `If-None-Match` headers if it can find a local cached item.

Now when you call `SetRequestHeader()` with either `If-(Un)Modified-Since` or `If-None-Match`, it'll clear both headers from the request and sets your value.

Comment: The server doesn't provide a Last-Modified header. The reason why the browser has to set the If-Modified-Since header (actually, only IE needs it) is to prevent IE's overly-aggressive caching. In my code I set If-Modified-Since to the current time, and in addition I also set "Cache-Control": "max-age=0".

Comment: @Tore see edit. It's the XHR implementation that does this. If you override the built-in caching by setting any related header, it removes all cache headers it has set.

Comment: You mean setRequestHeader(), not setResponseHeader()?